# Nagios Core Version 4.0.8 stopped sending automatic email notification after IP change

Tags: email, nagios3

I have Nagios Core Version 4.0.8 installed on Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS.
I changed the IP if the server and after that nagios wont send me automatic notifications, I have send email from root and nagios user by using mail -s "hello" "email@address" << EOF
message
EOF

And I the email from both users
When I run which mail I get /usr/**bin**/mail but I saw this in the logs

```
[1436932929] Warning: Notifying contact 'nagiosadmin' of service 'SSH' on host 'store9' by command '/usr/bin/printf "%b" "***** Nagios *****\n\nNotification Type: RECOVERY\n\nService: SSH\nHost: store9 kringlan\nAddress: 192.168.175.1\nState: OK\n\nDate/Time: Wed Jul 15 04:01:39 GMT 2015\n\nAdditional Info:\n\nSSH OK - OpenSSH_4.3 (protocol 2.0)\n" | /usr/**sbin**/sendmail -s "** RECOVERY Service Alert: store9 kringlan/SSH is OK **" email@address' timed out after 0.00 seconds
```

But no email.... I tried to change the /usr/sbin/sendmail to /usr/bin/sendmail
but got an error

I have rebooted the server, done service sendmail stop/start and service nagios restart

anyone have an idea what more I can try ?

Comment: can you `telnet localhost 25`?

Comment: Hello I stumbled onto a forum post that helped me solve this, had to edit /etc/hosts 
127.0.0.1       localhost.domain.local localhost Ubuntu-Backup.local   Ubuntu-Backup

Comment: Great. You find solution fast.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this by editing `/etc/hosts` to contain this:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost.domain.local localhost Ubuntu-Backup.local Ubuntu-Backup
```